# ¿Alguna manera de evitar múltiples if-elif consecutivos?

Tags: python, python-3.x

este es un programa simple (soy novato), para calcular la densidad de un metal, comparar y decir que tipo de metal es. El programa me funciona, pero después de darle vueltas me pregunto si hay alguna manera mas breve de hacer dos cosas:

1. ¿Hay alguna manera mas breve con respecto a este "statement"?

   if d >2400 and d <2700:
2. ¿Hay alguna manera de evitar tanto "elif"?

El programa corre y es este (python.3.8 en ubuntu20.4):

```
mass = float(input("Intro la masa de la corona en kg: "))

volume = float(input("Intro el volumen en metros cubicos, m3: "))

# Densidad = Masa / Volumen

d = mass/volume

if d >2400 and d <2700:
    print ("La corona es de Aluminio")

elif d >8100 and d <8300:
    print ("La corona es de Bronce")

elif d >10400 and d <10600:
    print ("La corona es de Plata")

elif d >11200 and d <11400:
    print ("La corona es de Plomo")

elif d >17100 and d < 17500:
    print ("La corona es de Oro")

elif d >21000 and d <21500:
    print ("La corona es de Platino")
```

Gracias por vuestro tiempo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mi objetivo con esta respuesta es mostrar múltiples maneras de mejorar tu código (de acuerdo a tu primera pregunta), de acuerdo a distintos paradigmas.

Empecemos con el paradigma que estás aplicando...

### Procedural

Podemos mejorar el código, sencillamente aprovechando el hecho de que Python permite la concatenación de operadores de comparación, tal como dice [la documentación oficial](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons). También podemos usar [interpolación de strings](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/string-interpolation), particularmente, la técnica de f-strings.

De esta manera, podemos escribir:

```
mass = float(input("Intro la masa de la corona en kg: "))
volume = float(input("Intro el volumen en metros cubicos, m3: "))

d = mass / volume

if 2400 < d < 2700:
    elemento = "Aluminio"
elif 8100 < d < 8300:
    elemento = "Bronce"

# ... todos las demás evaluaciones

print(f"La corona es de {element}")
```

### Orientada a Objetos

Ante todo, lo mostrado a continuación es un *overkill* grandísimo para este caso particular. Es como matar una mosca con el martillo de Thor y **no** debería ser implementado a no ser que en realidad nuestro sistema lo requiera.

También entiendo que estás pidiendo por una forma más breve de hacerlo, y sé que con esto no se consigue brevedad. De hecho, todo lo contrario.

Sin embargo, quiero aprovechar la oportunidad para introducir un Patrón de Diseño excelente, que puede ser usado en situaciones similares a esta. Es decir, en situaciones en las cuales se requiere la evaluación de una(s) condición(es) compleja(s) que definan, de una u otra manera, la línea de ejecución de nuestro programa.

Hablo del Patrón [Cadena de responsabilidad](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadena_de_responsabilidad) (o CoR, por sus siglas en inglés). Este patrón nos permite evitar el tener que hacer (y repetir) largas cadenas de `if`-`elif`-`else`, mientras mantenemos un bajo *coupling* entre los elementos que participan en dichas cadenas condicionales y dándonos, además, un poderoso control en la ejecución de la misma. Este control nos permite, incluso, controlar los elementos evaluados en las cadenas condicionales, en *runtime*.

Quiero mostrar, en primer lugar, cómo quedaría el código que aprovecha el patrón (llamado, frecuentemente, código "cliente").

```
mass = float(input("Intro la masa de la corona en kg: "))
volume = float(input("Intro el volumen en metros cubicos, m3: "))

d = mass / volume

first_handler = AluminioHandler()

(
    first_handler
    .set_next(BronceHandler())
    .set_next(PlataHandler())
    .set_next(PlomoHandler())
    .set_next(OroHandler())
    .set_next(PlatinoHandler())
)

element = first_handler.evaluate(d)
print(f"La corona es de {element}")
```

¿Interesante? Bueno, veamos cómo lo podemos implementar.

Primero, tenemos una clase *Handler* padre:

```
class BaseHandler:
    next_handler = None

    def set_next(self, handler):
        self.next_handler = handler
        return handler

    def evaluate(self, d):
        if self.next_handler:
            return self.next_handler.evaluate(d)
        return 'ningún elemento analizado'
```

Luego, clases hijas (*concrete handlers*) correspondientes a cada elemento que sobreescriban el método `evaluate()` para que, en caso de que se cumpla una condición, devolver el valor deseado.

```
class AluminioHandler(BaseHandler):
    def evaluate(self, d):
        if 2400 < d < 2700:
            return 'Aluminio'
        return super().evaluate(d)


class BronceHandler(BaseHandler):
    def evaluate(self, d):
        if 8100 < d < 8300:
            return 'Bronce'
        return super().evaluate(d)


class PlataHandler(BaseHandler):
    def evaluate(self, d):
        if 10400 < d < 10600:
            return 'Plata'
        return super().evaluate(d)


class PlomoHandler(BaseHandler):
    def evaluate(self, d):
        if 11200 < d < 11400:
            return 'Plomo'
        return super().evaluate(d)


class OroHandler(BaseHandler):
    def evaluate(self, d):
        if 17100 < d < 17500:
            return 'Oro'
        return super().evaluate(d)


class PlatinoHandler(BaseHandler):
    def evaluate(self, d):
        if 21000 < d < 21500:
            return 'Platino'
        return super().evaluate(d)
```

Listo. Ya con eso tendríamos implementado el Patrón CoR en nuestro código, deshaciéndonos de esas largas y molestas cadenas de `if`-`elif`-`else`.

### Funcional

Bueno, bueno, ahora sí vamos con una solución más breve. Esta manera también es bastante positiva, e inspirada también en el patrón CoR, pero es menos flexible que la solución puramente apegada al patrón, que acabo de dar arriba.

Acá usamos programación funcional, específicamente [closures](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausura_(inform%C3%A1tica)), aprovechando el hecho de que en Python las funciones son [First-Class citizens](https://realpython.com/lessons/functions-are-first-class-citizens-python/).

La similitud con el Patrón CoR viene dada a partir del uso de la builtin function `next()`, con la cual vamos evaluando la misma *request* hasta encontrar el elemento que satisfaga la evaluación.

Sería así:

```
NAME = 0
CONDITION = 1

mass = float(input("Intro la masa de la corona en kg: "))
volume = float(input("Intro el volumen en metros cubicos, m3: "))

d = mass / volume

def set_density_range(min_value, max_value):
    def evaluate(d):
        return min_value < d < max_value
    return evaluate

list_ = [
    ("Aluminio", set_density_range(2400, 2700)),
    ("Bronce", set_density_range(8100, 8300)),
    ("Plata", set_density_range(10400, 10600)),
    ("Plomo", set_density_range(11200, 11400)),
    ("Oro", set_density_range(17100, 17500)),
    ("Platino", set_density_range(21000, 21500)),
    ('ningún elemento analizado', lambda d: True)
]

element = next(item[NAME] for item in list_ if item[CONDITION](d) is True)
print(f"La corona es de {element}")
```

Comment: Fantastica explicacion. Muchisimas gracias por tanto tiempo. Justo el concepto que me aclara el primer punto es el de **"concatenación de operadores de comparación"**  Leeré la documentación. Muchas gracias @reviscano

Answer (score 1):

una alternativa seria crear un diccionario
ejemplo:

```
## todos los valores a comparar
coronas = { "Aluminio" : [2400,2700],
            "Bronce" : [8100,8300],
            "Plata" : [10400,10600],
            "Plomo" : [11200,11400],
            "Oro" : [17100,17500],
            "platino" : [21000,21500],
        }
# definimos la funcion corona
def corona(d):

    # recorremos el diccionario coronas
    for x in coronas:
        # aqui utlizamos un solo if para validar todos
        if( d > coronas[x][0] and  d < coronas[x][1]):
            # retornamos el tipo si coincide
            return "La corona es de {}".format(x)

    # o retornamos en caso de no encontrar ninguna coincidencia
    return "no se ajusta a ninguna de las coronas"


# provamos
d = 2402
r = corona(d)
print(r)
```

si no deseas utilizar una funcion puedes hacer:

```
d = 2402
# recorremos el diccionario coronas
for x in coronas:
    # aqui utlizamos un solo if para validar todos
    if( d > coronas[x][0] and  d < coronas[x][1]):
        # si tipo si coincide
        print("La corona es de {}".format(x))
        break

# trick: python permite tener un else para los for      
else:
    # en caso de no encontrar ninguna coincidencia
    print("no se ajusta a ninguna de las coronas")
```

Comment: Gracias Bryro. Me gusta la función y la solución del diccionario. NI lo habia pensado. Es mucho mas elegante que lo mio. Un saludo

Comment: Que buena info!!!, ahorita me pongo a trabajar en una tremenda cadena de IF a cambiarlo por diccionario XD

Answer (score -1):

Como sugerencia puedes ocupar CASE, aunque la verdad es similar, es otra opcion que es valida ocupar para lo que estas haciendo.

```
Case d = mass/volume
      Case d >2400 and d <2700: print ("La corona es de Aluminio")
      Case d >8100 and d <8300: print ("La corona es de Bronce")     
End Case
```

Comment: La respuesta no es Python.

Comment: Python no tiene `case`